# FlavorProperties GUID in csproj File

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

So I was looking at an open source's csproj file and noticed this:

```
<ProjectExtensions>
   <VisualStudio>
       <FlavorProperties GUID="{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}">
         <HostingProcess disable="1" />
       </FlavorProperties>
   </VisualStudio>
<ProjectExtensions>
```

What does this do to a C# project and what is it telling visual studio to do? MSDN has this to say but I wasn't entirely sure what they meant or where this would be applicable([MSDN MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165747%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)):

> A project subtype can also modify the XML fragment before or after it delegates the call to an inner project subtype. The following example shows an excerpt from a project file, where a name of a file that contains properties specific to a project subtype, is passed to that project subtype

Any insight is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That particular GUID (`FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC`) simply means it is a C# project. I established this by googling it, which is in general a good way to start to work out what the `FlavorProperties` GUIDs mean.

`HostingProcess disable="1"` refers to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185330%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> Calls to certain APIs can be affected
>   by enabling the hosting process. In
>   these cases, it is necessary to
>   disable the hosting process to return
>   the correct results. To disable the
>   hosting process
>
> - Open a project in Visual Studio.
> - On the Project menu, click Properties.
> - Click the Debug tab.
> - Clear the Enable the Visual Studio hosting process check box.
>
> When the hosting process is disabled,
>   several debugging features are
>   unavailable or experience decreased
>   performance. For more information, see
>   Debugging and the Hosting Process.
>
> In general, when the hosting process
>   is disabled:
>
> - The time needed to begin debugging .NET Framework applications increases.
> - Design-time expression evaluation is unavailable.
> - Partial trust debugging is unavailable.